# error redirecting not redirecting

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

When I am running one of my pages and someone changes the url to a non existing one, I want them to redirect to my login page. On the internet I found the following code, which I put in my Web.config file:

```
      <customErrors mode="On"
              defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/Login.aspx" />
```

I put this inside this:

```
    <system.web>
    </sytem.web>
```

However, this does not work for me, I still get to see this:

[image]

I tried to change the mode from On to Remote Only and vice versa, but that did not help. I also tried to change the defaultRedirect from ~/ErrorPages/Login.aspx to ~/Login.aspx but that also did not work. Can anyone help me out here? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

The Login.aspx page is located inside a subfolder called Pages. Unfortunately this: ~/Pages/Login.aspx doesn't work either

Comment: What is the location of your `login.aspx` page. It is not finding that file, that is why 404 error

Comment: Solution>Project>Pages>Login.apx (if that is what you mean), tried ~/Pages/Login.aspx but that also does not work

Answer (score 2):

```
<configuration>

   <system.web>
      <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />

      <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
         <error statusCode="404" redirect="login.aspx" />
      </customErrors>
   </system.web>
```

**Update** :
An error handler that is defined in the `Global.asax` file will only catch errors that occur during processing of requests by the `ASP.NET` runtime. For example, it will catch the error if a user requests an .aspx file that does not occur in your application. However, it does not catch the error if a user requests a nonexistent `.htm file`. For non-ASP.NET errors, you can create a `custom handler` in Internet Information Services (IIS). The custom handler will also not be called for server-level errors.
--[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You can also handle this error in your global.asax `Application_Error event`.

```
 protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpException serverError = Server.GetLastError() as HttpException;

        if (null != serverError)
        {
            int errorCode = serverError.GetHttpCode();

            if (404 == errorCode)
            {
                Server.ClearError();
                Server.Transfer("Your virtual path");

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @NiekJonkman Please check updated answer and try to handle it on global.asax file.

Comment: For now, I'll just leave this problem and catch up with it later but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your error, however it should look like this:

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/YourErrorPage.aspx">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPages/YourErrorPage.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/ErrorPages/YourErrorPage.aspx" />
</customErrors>
..........
.........
</sytem.web>
```

I would not point to the login page in case of errors because if you have an error on such page you will never come right. Rather place a linkLabel on the error page to get redirected to the login page.

Comment: @NiekJonkman My code is correct and also Suraj code is correct. Not sure about what you are doing and if there is something else wrong in your code. Try to ask your hosting provider what they are doing with the errors on IIS.